# Use stored fields instead of `_source` in elastic search using yii2

Tags: elasticsearch, yii2, yii2-extension

Yii2 provides an elastic search extension and also elastic search ActiveRecord class.

This elastic search extension seams to read the data from elastic by querying the `_source` field of elastic search, which is not ideal.

If fields in elastic are set to `"store" :true` it would be the better way to read the data from the stored field directly, not by querying the `_source` field which results in an implicit parsing of that field by elastic.

Is there a way to configure or use Yii2 / elaticsearch - extension to get the data from the stored fields? I didn't found any option or something else here: https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-elasticsearch/doc/api/2.1/yii-elasticsearch-activerecord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question in case someone else has the same problem:

If you like to run an query using active record in Yii2 on stored fields and if you like to get the data from the stored entry, not by parsing the `_source` filed, than you have th explicity specify the stored fields by using the `->storedFields()` - function from active record class.

Using active record it looks like this:

```
/* new instance from User model,
   which is based on `\yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord`*/
$user = new User();


/* '*' for all fileds instead of an array of fieldnames */
$query = $user -> find()
                    -> query('<your query object')
                    -> storedFields(['*']);
```